# How to find average order value and count in SQL when the rows are repeated? Interview question I didn't know to solve

Tags: mysql, sql

During my interview, I had a simple sounding question about calculating daily average number of orders and daily average revenue. But in the table, records were arranged like this: If I place an order with 4 items, the 4 items were shown as individual records with the same order ID. But the order_value column had only the total order value in all the 4 records. How can I calculate

1. The average daily order value and daily average number of orders?
2. How many orders were delivered within the preparation time of 20 minutes?

Giving the table below for reference:

[image]

Comment: Edit the question and post the data as text not image . Did you try something to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it.
You start by calculating the metrics per day.

> ```
> select 
>   date(order_date) as order_day
> , sum(final_bill) as daily_total_bill
> , count(order_id) as daily_orders
> , count(case 
>         when timestampdiff(minute, order_date, prepared_date) <= 20
>         then order_id
>         end) as daily_ontime
> from kitchen_orders
> group by date(order_date)
> ```

| order_day | daily_total_bill | daily_orders | daily_ontime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-01 | 95.30 | 3 | 3 |
| 2020-12-02 | 105.60 | 3 | 2 |

And then wrap that in a sub-query or cte, to get the averages and totals for all.

> ```
> select 
>  round(avg(daily_total_bill), 2) as avg_daily_bill, 
>  round(avg(daily_orders), 1) as avg_daily_orders, 
>  sum(daily_ontime) as total_ontime
> from
> (
>   select 
>       date(order_date) as order_day
>     , sum(final_bill) as daily_total_bill
>     , count(order_id) as daily_orders
>     , count(case 
>             when timestampdiff(minute, order_date, prepared_date) <= 20
>             then order_id
>             end) as daily_ontime
>     from kitchen_orders
>     group by date(order_date)
> ) q
> ```

| avg_daily_bill | avg_daily_orders | total_ontime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100.45 | 3.0 | 5 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=31515e97503421a1cb6ba65b22286182)*